# How to make foreign key accept field value instead of its id in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have created a checkbox for content filtering of products based on category.So when the user clicks on any checkbox only the books with that category should be shown.In the view I am passing the value of checkbox field(category name) obtained from the template but upon filtering, the foreign key is expecting pk(id) instead of field value.I am getting error like this,`invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<category name>'`.So is it possible to make foreign key accept value instead of id?

Models.py,

```
class Add_cat(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField("Name",max_length=25,unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0}'.format(self.category)

class Add_prod(models.Model):
    book = models.CharField("Book Name",max_length=40)
    author = models.CharField("Author",max_length=30)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField("Price")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True)
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Add_cat,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Template file,

```
{% for i in products %}
                <input type="checkbox" name="cat_name" value="{{i.cat}}">{{i.cat}}<br>  
{% endfor %}
```

Views.py,

```
def welcome_user(request):        
    if 'cat_name' in request.GET:
        filter_category = request.GET.get('cat_name')
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.filter(cat__in = filter_category) 
        context = { "products":my_products}
    else:
        my_products = Add_prod.objects.all()
        context = { "products":my_products}
    return render(request,"welcome-user.html",context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in the `category` field itself:

```
my_products = Add_prod.objects.filter(cat__category__in=filter_category)
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) on how this works.

---

Above, is only applicable if `filter_category` is a `list`. If it is a string you can filter like following:

```
my_products = Add_prod.objects.filter(cat__category=filter_category)
```

Comment: I ran in debug mode,upon entering this line QuerySet list is becoming empty and hence blank output.So can u update your answer?

Comment: Please check what values are you getting in `filter_category`? If the values are correct you will get the correct results.

Comment: `__in` looks if a value is in an array :)

Comment: I just assumed that  `filter_category` is an array considering what OP has already done `cat__in`.

Comment: I'd have thought they would be using `get_list` if it were an array, you could be right though.

Comment: Yes, as @Sayse suggested in the comment above, you can use `getlist` to get all the values.

Comment: Its completely working now,for string I can use get() and for list I can use getlist()

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,it will help you:

```
Add_prod.objects.filter(cat__category = filter_category)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong with your code

1. You need to look up the field rather than the foreign key
2. By using `__in` you are looking the category is equal to any one of the characters in the `filter_category`.

Hence to fix, use the field lookup and remove the `__in`

```
Add_prod.objects.filter(cat__category=filter_category)
```